# Import from data file into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below shows should import values
from the temps.txt file but the times array
appears empty , what could be wrong?

I only get "Nan" as output.

The temps.txt file looks like this:

```
21.5
22.3
... etc
```

Here's my sourcecode:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var times = [];

 $.get('temps.txt', function(data) {
    times = data.split("\n");
  });
for (var i in times)
 {
    document.write(times[i] + "<BR />");
 }

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: $.get is an aynch call and your for loop should go inside the callback function, just after times = data.split("\n");

Comment: Also, don't use `document.write`. It replaces everything on the document each time you use it. Create an element with jQuery and append other elements to it.

Comment: I'd like to keep the data in the times array or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

1) Move the loop into the `$.get` callback.

2) Use an array to build up your string

3) Append it to the body element using `join`.

```
$.get('temps.txt', function(data) {
  times = data.split("\n");
  var html = [];
  for (var i in times) {
    html.push(times[i] + '<br/>');
  }
  $('body').append(html.join(''));
});
```